# Highcharts line chart, hover over point selects another point on chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

To my chart I pass data as array of arrays of UTC datetime and value, e.g :

```
[
  [1374537600000, 69.67575704891426]  
  [1373932800000, 69.67575704891426]
]
```

I hard-coded the data values in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tenonic/xZjsF/).
When you hover over point, **another point is selected** for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts should be able to handle this without resulting in your issue, but you need to switch the order of the data:

```
data: 
[
  [1373932800000, 69.67575704891426],
  [1374537600000, 69.67575704891426]
]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/xZjsF/2/)

Comment: you got it. Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: because highcharts assumes that what comes before in the data array will be an earlier date than what comes after.

Comment: In the highcharts, data should be sorted by x ascending.